# error 1004 the supplied path must be an valid absolute path

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to import multiple csv files into excel. I ran the macro recorder and got most of the code I that I have. The code worked when I had the actual file path but once I substituted the actual path with a variable. I have tried 6 or 7 combinations with no luck. The error is caused on the .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False line. But the error happened when I changed the line  from 
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Documents and Settings\Parents\Downloads\DBO.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=6,

Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(Chr(34) & Chr(39) & strFullPath & Chr(39) & Chr(34)),[Delimiter="","",
 My code is below:

```
                        Public Sub ImportFiles()

                            Dim xStrPath As String
                            Dim xFile As String
                            Dim xFiles As New Collection
                            Dim I As Long
                            Dim lastRowSrc As Long
                            Dim lastRowDest As Long
                            Dim strFileName As String
                            Dim destWB As Workbook
                            Dim destWS As Worksheet
                            Dim srcWB As Workbook
                            Dim strSrcFile As String
                            Dim strDestFile As Worksheet
                            Dim strColRow As String
                            Dim strFullPath As String


                                xStrPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Parents\Downloads\"
                                If Right(xStrPath, 1) <> "\" Then xStrPath = xStrPath & "\"
                                xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "*.csv")
                                strFileName = Left(xFile, 3)
                                lastRowDest = Sheets(strFileName).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                                strColRow = "$A$" & lastRowDest

                            Do While xFile <> ""
                                xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
                                xFile = Dir()
                            Loop
                                Set destWB = Workbooks.Add

                            If xFiles.Count > 0 Then
                                For I = 1 To xFiles.Count
                                    Set srcWB = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I))

                                    Stop
                                    strSrcFile = xFiles.Item(I)
                                    strFullPath = xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I)
                                    strFileName = Left(xFiles.Item(I), 3)

                                    destWB.Activate


                                'Run-time error 1004
                                'the import Chr matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?
                                 destWB.Queries.Add Name:=strFileName, Formula:= _
                                        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(Chr(34) & Chr(39) & strFullPath & Chr(39) & Chr(34)),[Delimiter="","", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""date"", type date}, {""close" & _
                                        """, type number}, {""volume"", Int64.Type}, {""open"", type number}, {""high"", type number}, {""low"", type number}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""


                                    With destWB.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
                                        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
                                         , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
                                        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
                                        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM " & strFileName)
                                        .RowNumbers = False
                                        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                                        .PreserveFormatting = True
                                        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                                        .BackgroundQuery = True
                                        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                                        .SavePassword = False
                                        .SaveData = True
                                        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                                        .RefreshPeriod = 0
                                        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
                                        .ListObject.DisplayName = strFileName
                                        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                                    End With

                                    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = strFileName
                                    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(strFileName)
                                        .ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
                                        .ShowTableStyleRowStripes = False
                                        .TableStyle = ""
                                        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
                                        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
                                        Range("DBO[date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
                                        :=xlSortNormal
                                    End With

                                    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strFileName).ListObjects(strFileName).Sort
                                        .MatchCase = False
                                        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                                        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                                        .Apply
                                    End With


                                    Set destWS = destWB.Worksheets(I)
                                    Call FixSheet(destWB, destWS)
                                Next
                            End If
                        End Sub
```

Comment: Whats the value of `strFullPath`? Use a watch or `MsgBox` or `Debug.Print` to see what's in that variable at runtime.

Comment: Thanks , the file I was trying to import was corrupted. Now the code works